# How to stop TFLearn from printing everything

Tags: tflearn

When I run TFLearn, my console prints out every single iteration as shown below. Snapshot step doesn't do anything. Can i just delete the line of code that does this somewhere or a parameter to turn it off?

```
Training Step: 7790  | total loss: 0.00591 | time: 9.970s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00591 - acc: 0.9988 -- iter: 03200/55000
Training Step: 7791  | total loss: 0.00540 | time: 10.025s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00540 - acc: 0.9989 -- iter: 03264/55000
Training Step: 7792  | total loss: 0.00505 | time: 10.089s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00505 - acc: 0.9990 -- iter: 03328/55000
Training Step: 7793  | total loss: 0.00480 | time: 10.155s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00480 - acc: 0.9991 -- iter: 03392/55000
Training Step: 7794  | total loss: 0.00503 | time: 10.215s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00503 - acc: 0.9992 -- iter: 03456/55000
Training Step: 7795  | total loss: 0.00973 | time: 10.274s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00973 - acc: 0.9962 -- iter: 03520/55000
Training Step: 7796  | total loss: 0.00879 | time: 10.337s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00879 - acc: 0.9965 -- iter: 03584/55000
Training Step: 7797  | total loss: 0.00824 | time: 10.406s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00824 - acc: 0.9969 -- iter: 03648/55000
Training Step: 7798  | total loss: 0.00759 | time: 10.464s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00759 - acc: 0.9972 -- iter: 03712/55000
Training Step: 7799  | total loss: 0.00690 | time: 10.523s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00690 - acc: 0.9975 -- iter: 03776/55000
```

EDIT: it is probably a windows issue and cmd

Answer (score 0):

As of right now there seems to be no way to disable this in TFLearn.
Your best bet seems to be editing the source code.